# How to ignore spaces while reading text file?

Tags: visual-c++

In my code I parse a txt file using vectors the txt file contains:

```
 111|01-11111|TVNX0020430301519114|A45N9|Lions Gate Entertainment|Redemption 2013 HD|$5.99|2014-01-23T12:55|WATVC|35555|0003E6420F88|STB|
```

I want to write this data into Excel. By using vectors I did parsing is the code:

```
vector< vector<string> >  data;


void parse(const char* name)
{
    ifstream in(name);

  string line;

  // read the file
  while ( getline(in,line,'|') ) 
  {
    vector<string> fields;
    std::stringstream    linestream(line);
    for ( int col = 0 ; col < 21 ; col++ ) 
    {
      string f;
      linestream >> f;
      fields.push_back(f);
     fields.erase(std::remove_if(fields.begin(), fields.end(), isspace),fields.end());          
    }
    data.push_back(fields);
   } 
   for ( vector< vector<string> >::size_type row = 0 ; row < data.size() ; row++ )
   {

    for ( vector<string>::size_type col = 0 ; col < data[row].size() ; col++ ) 
    {

        cout << data[row][col];

    }
    cout << endl;
  }
  }
```

I want to separate only pipe and "\n" I dont want to separate string with space so I can write full string into one header.

I'm using to ignore spaces erase

```
fields.erase(std::remove_if(fields.begin(), fields.end(), isspace),fields.end());
```

It's giving error:

```
error C2664: 'int (int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'int'
        with
        [
            _Elem=char,
            _Traits=std::char_traits,
            _Ax=std::allocator
        ]
        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

Comment: replace the pipes with commas , write the string to a file , name it with extension .csv

Comment: that file is genrated by server i cannt replace it